# How to find multiple intersection points of two contour plots in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, intersection, contour, shapely

I have plotted two contour plots onto the same graph in Python. The two plots have multiple intersection points. I have found a single intersection point, but I am wanting to find all possible intersection points.

Here is the code I used to find a single intersection point:

```
 from shapely import geometry
 def findIntersection(contour1, contour2):
      p1 = contour1.collections[0].get_paths()[0]
      v1 = p1.vertices
      p2 = contour2.collections[0].get_paths()[0]
      v2 = p2.vertices
      poly1 = geometry.LineString(v1)
      poly2 = geometry.LineString(v2)
      intersection = pol1.intersection(poly2)
      return intersection
 intersection_example = findIntersection(contour1, contour2)
 print(list(intersection_example.coords))
```

Here is the output:

> [(2.280337504875689, 0.1641120502440566)]

As you can see, the code outputs a single solution pair, but I am wanting all solution pairs.

[image: Here is the image of the contour plot that I wish to find all the intersection points for]

Comment: Could you also provide an example of input data?

Comment: @Georgy, I added a picture of the contour plot that serves as the input data. I hope this helps!

Comment: Could you also provide a code to generate this plot? This will help a lot.